# how to call stored procedure inside trigger and set value on varible?

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Leave_applied_table FOR EACH ROW
begin

   set mangerid= CALL Managers_SP (new.employee_id);
     insert into Leave_actula_table (Leave_actula_table.leave_applied_id,and so ON....) values(new.employee_id,new.leave_type_id) ;

     insert into Leave_approval_table (Leave_approval_table.leave_applied_id, and so on....) values (new.employee_id and so on;

END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In the above code, I am trying to call Stored Procedure inside trigger  and I want to set on variable.

`CALL Managers_SP (new.employee_id`) returns manger id and I want to set it in `mangerid`. But it shows Syntax Error.

How can I call it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Try using `new.managerid =` instead of `managerid =` since you are in an insert trigger

Comment: where i have to use this one ? @rypskar 5

Comment: You have used this on line 5 `set mangerid= CALL Managers_SP (new.employee_id);` should probably be `new.mangerid= CALL Managers_SP (new.employee_id);`

Comment: new.mangerid  this we have declare in trigger?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL Managers_SP(new.employee_id);       insert into leave_actual (leave_applied' at line 10  ) error is coming @rypskar

Comment: Seems like I did miss a miss the set keyword. Should be `set new.mangerid= CALL Managers_SP (new.employee_id);` But the problem can also be that you have a stored procedure not a stored function. AFAIK only functions return a value, while stored procedures need an out parameter to get a result from it